# How or *will* totally changing established membership types affect reporting?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Organization has an established membership structure.  They now want to completely overhaul this system and add new for both renewals and new members.  Worried about future reporting issues.  Is there a process I should follow?

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question.  Please edit your post to include details of existing structure, and of the new structure with how you intend transitioning from one to the other .  Also what is currently reported and what reporting is required in the future.